# Latex footnotes no text

Tags: latex

Footnote-marks are visible but its footnote-texts did not show up in the compiled dokument (compiles w/o any error)
Is there any known conflict in this regarding the used packages?
i am not able to find the issue.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % hiermit werden deutsche Bezeichnungen   
genutzt und 
                 % die W\"orter werden anhand der neue Rechtschreibung 
         % automatisch getrennt.  
\usepackage[resetlabels]{multibib}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\apptocmd{\sloppy}{\hbadness 10000\relax}{}{}
\counterwithin{figure}{section}
\newcites{All}{Bibliographie}
\newcites{R}{Referenzen}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
% Damit die Verwendung der deutschen Sprache nicht ganz so umst\"andlich 
wird,
% sollte man die folgenden Pakete einbinden: 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{a4wide}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % das Trennen der Umlaute
\usepackage{url}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\title{Literatur-Review}
\author{  \\
Jan }
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{\includegraphics[scale=0.908]
{images/cover.png}}
\end{titlepage}
\newpage
%set the hierarchical drilldown to 3
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} \setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
%set pagination to Roman numerals and begin at page i
\pagenumbering{roman} \setcounter{page}{0}
\mbox{}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-.1in}
\tableofcontents{}
\clearpage
%%------------List of Figures----------------------
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Figures}
\listoffigures{}
\clearpage
%%-----------Table of Contents-----------------
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Tables}
\listoftables{}
\clearpage
%change single space to double space

%maintain Roman numerals on the previous page
\clearpage
%set pagination to Arabic
\pagenumbering{arabic} 
%include the other .tex files 
test\footnote{test}
\newpage
%%bibliographie
\nociteAll{*}
\bibliographystyleR{apacite}
\bibliographyR{lit}                 
\bibliographystyleAll{apacite}
\end{document}
\bibliographyAll{lit}                   
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please create a MWE (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve); the code above contents local images as well as non-standard tex packages. This question, however, seems more of code review type rather than a technical one. What have you tried? Have your tried disabling one of your other packages on by on to see if one of them possible is the cause of your footnotes being left out? This is something you could do yourself, and thereafter ask a more specific question; e.g. "Why does the ... package seemingly remove my footnote texts? <include MWE>".

Comment: seems that footnotes does not work if a4wide is used.. its kind of a bug imo.. the footer seems to get "overwritten"